# How to differentiate a derivative with respect to a different variable?

Tags: derivatives

For a measured variable $x$ with error $\delta x$, the error on the function $y=f(x)$ is defined to be:

$$ \delta y = \Biggl| \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \Biggr| \space \delta x $$

My problem is how to apply this to the following function:

$$ \alpha (t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Bigl(\mathrm{ln}\bigl(x(t)\bigr)\Bigr) $$

i.e. what is the error $\delta \alpha$ arising from the measurement error $\delta x$? I'm assuming it is:

$$ \delta \alpha = \Biggl| \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \Biggl( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{ln}(x) \Biggr) \Biggr| \space \delta x$$

but I am struggling with differentiating a derivative with respect to a different variable. I imagine it involves applying the chain rule but my maths is not strong enough to work this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case as the input the function $\alpha$ is $t$, I guess you want to calculate error in $\alpha$ for an error in $t$. So it has to be,

$\delta \alpha = \Biggl| \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \Biggl( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{ln}(x(t)) \Biggr) \Biggr| \space \delta t$

The way you simplify $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{ln}(x(t))$ is by chain rule of differentiation see, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

and you get $= \frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}$ which you need find derivative again with respect to $t$ again by chain rule.

EDIT after your comment:

It is better to start with the simplified form of the given function,

$\alpha (t) = \frac{x_{t}(t)}{x(t)}$ now as you suggested there is measurement error with respect to $x$ so this implies,

$\delta \alpha = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \Biggl( \frac{x_{t}(t)}{x(t)} \Biggr) \space \delta x$

Evaluating $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \Biggl( \frac{x_{t}(t)}{x(t)} \Biggr) $ gives

$= \Biggl(\frac{d(x_t)}{dx}x - x_{t} \Biggr)/x^2 = \frac{-x_t}{x^2}$

by $x_t$, I mean derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$

Comment: In my case, the input is $x(t)$ and the measurement error is on $x$ (it is assumed that the error in $t$ is negligible). So I think it does need to be as in the question. The reason why $\alpha$ is a function of $t$ and not $x$ is that it's not dependent on the magnitude of $x$, only on the rate of change of $x$.

Comment: even then it means, it is function of $x$. The source of error has to be $t$ may be $x(t)$ is a function which amplifies the small error in t. In case you don't want to worry about $t$ and only about x then rewrite as $\alpha (x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{ln}(x(t))$, $t$ doesn't come into picture, meaning for at fixed $t$

Comment: Maybe I've been unclear. I will try and explain more. There are points of data $x$, measured in time. There is a fitted function $x(t)$ that approximates these measured data points (assumed to be the true underlying function) and the error in the $x$ values is defined from the standard deviation from the fitted function. The $\alpha$ is derived from this fitted function. The goal therefore is to define the error in $\alpha$ due to the measurement error $\delta x$.

Comment: Sorry if I'm sounding a bit thick here, but you say that by $x_{t}$ you mean derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$, but isn't that what $x'$ means?

Comment: Yes it is the same, just wanted to make things clearer as $x'$ clearly doesn't say if it is a derivative with respect to $x$ or $t$